# Rational $F_n$ Limit $\to$ Find Denominator Polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials, roots, rational-functions

Given: $P(x)$ is a polynomial such that the following apply:

> I)  $\lim_\limits{x \to 1} \dfrac{P(x)}{(x-1)^3} = 6$
>
> II). $\lim_\limits{x \to -2} \dfrac{P(x)}{x^2+x-2} = 9$
>
> III) $\lim_\limits{x \to -\infty}\dfrac{P(x)}{(x+7)^6} = 0$

Find explicit formula for $p(x)$?

A) Calculation:

1) By the rule that if the degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator $\lim_\limits{x \to -\infty}=0$ holds for III.  Therefore, $P(x)$ is less than a 6th degree polynomial.

2) Factoring the denominator of II leads to $(x+2)(x-1)$.  Therefore, there is a discontinuity at $x=-2$ and $x=1$ for $P(x)$.

B) 
Further more:

3) I tried to make a polynomial in the numerator which would divide out the discontinuities in the denominator so made a polynomial of $(x+2)(x-1)^3$ which seems to work for II and III on graphing calculator.

4) In addition, the limits of I and II are factors of $3$.  This leads me to believe there is a factor in the numerator which will involve $3$.

Comment: Use the third equation to conclude that $\deg p<6$. Use the others to conclude that $(x-1)^3(x+2)$ divides $p(x)$ ...

Answer (score 2):

It should be $$P(x)=(x-1)^3(x+2)(ax+b),$$
which gives the system:
$$-2a+b=-\frac{1}{3}$$ and $$a+b=2.$$
I got $$P(x)=\frac{1}{9}(x-1)^3(x+2)(7x+11).$$

Comment: @Rozenberg System of 2 linear equations Not too sure where come from?

Comment: @JDragon314159 From given limits. The second equation it's $3(a⋅1+b)=6.$ The first it's $(−2−1)^3(a⋅(−2)+b)=9$

Comment: @Rozenberg $P(1) = (1-1)^3(1+2)(a*1+b) = 6$ 
$P(-2) = (-2-1)^3(-2+2)(a*-2+b) = 9$ Very Good! TY

Comment: @JDragon314159 YAW! :)